# Find the probability that a measurement results in a certain interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-algebras

I was given this problem:
Let the state $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ and an operator $P=-i\frac{d}{dx}$.

(a) What is the probability that a measure of P results in the interval $[0,1]$

(b) What is the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$.

Question: Why is (a) asked before (b), wouldn't we need to use the result from (b) to compute (a)?

Comment: Could you define "measurement of $P$" for the non-initiated ?

Comment: oh...this is actually quantum mechanics, f(x) is a state of a physical system, and P is some property of the state (i.e position, momentum etc). The measurement returns a number. And we are trying to find the probability that the number will be between 0 and 1.

Comment: If it's quantum mechanics, shouldn't it be $f(x)=e^{-\color{red}{\bf i}|x|}$?